# Update mysql table through python script

Tags: python, mysql

**I have been trying to use MySql with Python and I had been using mysql connector.**

Whenever I use cursor to execute commands, it works while the script is running but when I run the script again, the changes I made are gone.

Please help!
*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 2):

You need to commit the changes to the database with:

```
cursor.commit()
```

Otherwise they will reset when the cursor gets deleted.

Comment: Let me try it but I am starting to remember that it is the right one. A very warm thanks bro!!